# Generic async function to handle different models

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am trying to perform an action which accepts a type of model parameter and performs some action and then returns the type of same model parameter.

The models are defined in an external DLL and cannot be modified.

I am currently trying to achieve the functionality by

```
private async Task<Model1> ExecuteTask(Task<Model1> model)
{
    //perform some action
}

private async Task<Model2> ExecuteTask(Task<Model2> model)
{
    //perform some action
}

private async Task<Model3> ExecuteTask(Task<Model3> model)
{
    //perform some action
}
```

Is there a generic way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out the solution

```
private const int RequestTimeoutInMilliseconds = 10000;

public async Task<T> ExecuteTask<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(RequestTimeoutInMilliseconds)).ConfigureAwait(false) == task)
    {
        return task.Result;
    }

    throw new OperationCanceledException(typeof(T) + " Task failed");
}
```

For making a call

```
var task = client.ApiAsync();
var responseResult = task.ExecuteTask().Result
```

UPDATE: I am not sure as to why this answer received a downvote. The idea is to not care of the type of the model and just execute the task without the knowledge of the type of model.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a generic function/class to hold the implementation but provide they are from same abstract/base class `basemodel`

```
 public async T ExecuteTask<T>(T s) where T : Task<BaseModel>
 {
     // perform some actions.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If those models do not inherit from a common base class and do not implement the same interface, then there would not be a "neat" way (that I know of) to do that. You could make a function that takes in an `Object` and then you can attempt to cast it to one of the models, but the return value would again need to be an `Object`.